# Spanning and subsets

Tags: linear-algebra

I encountered this question while proving the following: if $S$ is a subset of $V$ then $\text{span}(S)$ is a subspace of $V$. I proved that $\text{span}(S)$ is a vector space by using the subspace test. But i think that for $\text{span}(S)$ to be a subspace it also needs to be that $\text{span}(S)$ is a subset of $V$. My question is: is this true?

Comment: How are you defining Span($S$)?  Some people would define it to be the smallest subspace of $V$ which contains $S$, which would make the problem trivial.  If you are defining it as the set of linear combinations of elements in $S$...well, then we know that $V$ is closed under addition and scalar multiplication.

Comment: An element of $\text{span}(S)$ is a linear combination of elements of $S$, which is a linear combination of elements of $V$. By the definition of a vector space, scaling and adding vectors of $V$ will always yield other vectors in $V$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$Span(S)$ being a subspace of $V$ implies $Span(S)\subset V$ (subspace is finer structure than subset). This does not go other way around, though. $S\subset V$ is sufficient for $Span(S)$ to be subset (and subspace) of $V$.